# How to read the "error" content generated in the command line using Python?

Tags: python, linux

Test is on Linux 32bit. Python 2.7

I want to run this command in Python

```
 nasm -f elf target.s
```

and collect the assembly error message this command generates such as these:

```
target.s:422: error: symbol `loc_8049B1C' undefined
target.s:423: error: symbol `loc_80499E8' undefined
target.s:424: error: symbol `loc_80499AE' undefined
```

I firstly use this:

```
infos = subprocess.check_output(["nasm", "-f", "elf", "final.s"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Python tells me that

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['nasm', '-f', 'elf', 'target.s']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

and program terminated

Then I use this:

```
 infos = os.popen("nasm -f elf target.s").read()
```

Then infos gets nothing.

So basically could anyone tell me how to get the error message info while keeping the Python program running as normal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the .communicate() to get the standard error if any.

```
s = 'nasm -f elf target.s'
proc = subprocess.Popen(s.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if stderr:
    print stderr
```

Comment: I was going to post this answer, almost verbatim, before I posted my other answer. My assumption was that there was some specific reason that "check_output" is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Check output raises a CalledProcessError when the process has a non-zero return status.

The output should be in the output attribute of the exception object.

```
try:
  infos = subprocess.check_output(["nasm", "-f", "elf", "final.s"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print e.output
```